# Debug failed with IAR Embedded workbench IDE

Tags: debugging, iar

I'm trying to run an example code on Texas instrument (TI) device: MSP430F2274.  When I click the debug button, this error occurs:

```
Fatal Error: failed to initialize device.
Session aborted.
```

In the Regular Options for the project I select the device and use the "FET debugger".

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your FET debugger may have some issues. Try using another FET debugger to see if you have the encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the FET debugger or your COM port selection. Ensure that when you select the FET debugger you set the current COM port number instead of "Automatic". If you still see the error after setting the port, it could be another fault with the FET debugger. Compare your settings with mine below:

```
GENERAL OPTIONS:
target:MSP430F2274,OUTPUT:executable,LIBRARY CONFIGURATION:CLIB
DEBUGGER: DRIVER: FETDEBUGGER, RUN TO: main
FET DEBUGGER: CONNECTION: Texas Instrument USB-IF, [COM Port]
```